# Error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input

Tags: javascript, json, django, ajax

There is the following script.

```
var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (JSON.parse(ajax.responseText).result == 'error') {
        console.log('error')
        $.each(JSON.parse(ajax.responseText).response, function(key, value) {
            console.log(key)
            $('.contact_form_' + key).css('display', 'block')
            $('.contact_form_' + key).prev().css("border", '1px solid #FD7900')
            $('.contact_form_' + key).text(value)
        })
    } else {
        location.reload();
    }
}
```

It is intended for an `ajax` request to the server. In response, from the server I pass `json` with the data. Empty `json` may come.

I get the following error.

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input

Swears at this line - `if (JSON.parse (ajax.responseText) .result == 'error') {`

`Json` examples that may come

```
if contact_form.is_valid():
    contact_form = contact_form.save()
    return JsonResponse({})
else:
    response = {}
    for k in contact_form.errors:
        response[k] = contact_form.errors[k][0]
    return JsonResponse({"response": response, 'result': 'error'})
```

**log**

[image]

Comment: You need to check the browser "Network" developer tab and look at what's being returned from the server.

Comment: Check the status of your XMLHttpRequest before just parsing `responseText`: This is what the docs say about `responseText`: Returns a `DOMString` that contains the response to the request as text, or `null` if the request was unsuccessful or has not yet been sent. So it could be `null`.

Comment: `JSON.parse("");` will give an error "(index):1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at window.onload ((index):32)" so it is probably an empty value.

Comment: @Pointy from server I get `{"response": {"name": "Share details, please.", "email": "Share details, please.", "text": "Share details, please."}, "result": "error"}`

Comment: @dirkgroten 200 status

Comment: Add a console.log in your script to print ajax.responseText. Something isn’t correct.

Comment: @dirkgroten I add `console.log(ajax.responseText)` after `if (JSON.parse(ajax.responseText).result == 'error') {` I get `json response`, 
which is repeated twice. And if I write `console.log(ajax.responseText)` before `if (JSON.parse(ajax.responseText).result == 'error') {` I get this log - https://i.imgur.com/xNLehQq.png.

Comment: Can’t read your image too low quality. Please just paste it in your question.

Comment: Basically, I solved this problem by checking `if (ajax.responseText) {` before `if (JSON.parse (ajax.responseText) .result == 'error') {`. But the `log` is still displayed twice. I wonder why this happens? ..

Comment: See [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/readyState) for an explanation of `onreadystatechange`. The problem is that you get multiple state changes when sending your xhr request and you should only run your function when the DONE state is reached.

Comment: Use the “onload” event or “load” event listener instead of “readystatechange”. Read [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest)

Comment: @dirkgroten thanks. I solved it by `if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you’re triggering your function on every state change of your `xhr` request. But not every state change means that a completed response has been sent.

[Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/readyState) is the list of state changes. As you can see, only the `DONE` state is relevant for parsing the response.

So in the other states your function will try to parse an empty `responseText`.  Also you might have already a `responseText` in an earlier stage.

If you read [the instructions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest) you’ll see that the recommended event to listen to is the `load` event.

Answer (score 0):

I changed

```
res.status(204).json({ user });
```

To

```
res.status(200).json({ user });
```

And it worked like a charm!